# Removing values depending on lookup condition

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, lookup

I have the following kind of dataframe, with thousands of columns and rows. First column contains dates, and the following columns contain asset return index corresponding to that date.

| DATE | Asset_1 | Asset_2 | Asset_3 | Asset_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2000 | 1000 | 300 | 2900 | **NA** |
| 2/1/2000 | 1100 | 350 | 2950 | **NA** |
| 3/1/2000 | 1200 | 330 | 2970 | 100 |
| 4/1/2000 | 1200 | 360 | 3000 | 200 |
| 5/1/2000 | 1200 | 370 | 3500 | 300 |

My problem is that delisted assets, such as Asset_1 in my example, remain in my dataset after the delisting, distorting my further processing. I have another dataframe where the delisting dates of the assets are listed. For example:

| ASSET_CODE | DELIST_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| Asset_1 | 3/1/2000 |
| Asset_2 | **NA** |
| Asset_3 | **NA** |
| Asset_4 | **NA** |

What i want to achieve, is to remove all observations from delisted assets after the delisting date, i.e. if DATE>DELIST_DATE(ASSET_CODE). This would be quite straightforward in Excel using a combination of IF and indexmatching, but can't figure how to do this in R.

My desired output would be:

| DATE | Asset_1 | Asset_2 | Asset_3 | Asset_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2000 | 1000 | 300 | 2900 | **NA** |
| 2/1/2000 | 1100 | 350 | 2950 | **NA** |
| 3/1/2000 | 1200 | 330 | 2970 | 100 |
| 4/1/2000 | **NA** | 360 | 300 | 200 |
| 5/1/2000 | **NA** | 370 | 350 | 300 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a join + filter. But you have two add'l steps that need to be taken care of.

1. convert the dates to a `Date` data format so they can be compared chronologically. While Excel famously likes to make everything into a date, R needs to be told that your character string represents a date and shouldn't be sorted "alphabetically."
2. For a join, it's easier if your data is in long format.

---

4 of the seven steps below relate to the dates and reshaping.

```
library(dplyr)
asset_returns %>%
  mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%                     # DATES
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-DATE, names_to = "ASSET_CODE") %>%          # RESHAPE
  left_join(delistings) %>%
  mutate(DELIST_DATE = as.Date(DELIST_DATE, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%       # DATES
  filter(DATE <= DELIST_DATE | is.na(DELIST_DATE)) %>%
  select(-DELIST_DATE) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = ASSET_CODE, values_from = value) # RESHAPE
```

Result

```
Joining, by = "ASSET_CODE"
# A tibble: 5 × 5
  DATE       Asset_1 Asset_2 Asset_3 Asset_4
  <date>       <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1 2000-01-01    1000     300    2900      NA
2 2000-02-01    1100     350    2950      NA
3 2000-03-01    1200     330    2970     100
4 2000-04-01      NA     360    3000     200
5 2000-05-01      NA     370    3500     300
```

---

Reproducible data

```
asset_returns <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  DATE = c("1/1/2000","2/1/2000",
           "3/1/2000","4/1/2000","5/1/2000"),
  Asset_1 = c(1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1200L, 1200L),
  Asset_2 = c(300L, 350L, 330L, 360L, 370L),
  Asset_3 = c(2900L, 2950L, 2970L, 3000L, 3500L),
  Asset_4 = c(NA, NA, 100L, 200L, 300L)
)

delistings <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
        ASSET_CODE = c("Asset_1", "Asset_2", "Asset_3", "Asset_4"),
       DELIST_DATE = c("3/1/2000", NA, NA, NA)
              )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you response. it works perfectly with the reproducible data.. but not with my dataset :( the code runs fine but nothing happens to my data.

The dates are already taken of, so I commented those lines out. 

From what I can see the classes of my data should be similar, so that shouldn't be a problem? However my returns are stored as doubles, and my asset names are stored as characters. For example '123456' and '123X56' can be asset codes. Are there some modifications i need to make to account for this?

Comment: Okay I broke down the code from you in format without the pipe operator, and seems like the date columns had different classes for some reason. Added a piece of code where I change both date columns to integer (instead of dates) and now it works perfectly. huge thanks for doing the hard part!

Comment: Interesting, perhaps one was a datetime (POSIXct or POSIXlt)? Compare `library(lubridate); as.numeric(ymd(20000101)); as.numeric(ymd_h(2000010100))`: different values, with the date being an integer counting days since the start of 1970, but the datetime counting seconds since then as a floating point number.

Comment: Originally my dates were in the excel format, i.e. '30529' for 1/8/1983, so I had converted both the DATE and DELIST_DATE columns to dates using as.Date

Comment: `janitor::excel_numeric_to_date` is another option, but one weird thing to look out for is that excel for PC and excel for macs uses a different epoch starting date!